# Prove that there exists a language L ⊆ {0}^∗ that is not Turing decidable.

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

I was revising for my final and got this question. I don't see there exists such a language. Is it really existing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ whose membership problem is not Turing decidable, I think that $\{x \in \{0\}^\ast \mid |x| \in N\}$ is a good candidate for being not Turing decidable as well...

Comment: So basically the whole set is not Turing decidable? $$|x| \in N$$ includes all non-negative integers right?

Comment: @TerryWindwalker no, read my post.

Comment: I see, membership problem is not Turing decidable. I will work on that.